# How to add 'Administrator' to site collection owners for all users' personal sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, onedrive-for-business

I want to add 'Administrator'(Site Collection Administrator) to site collection owners for all users' personal sites(OneDrive for Business sites) programmatically(preferably using REST API) in Office365 .

How to do this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in office365 or SP on premise?

Comment: 'Administrator' is the site collection administrator or an arbitrary user?

Comment: The answer has been provided here by PirateEric: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138562/add-personal-site-collection-administrator-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Recently my research on `OD4B` have taken me to [Add a Site Collection administrator to all Site Collections in a Tenant by Vardhaman Deshpande](http://www.vrdmn.com/2015/04/add-site-collection-administrator-to.html), which gives example on how to add `site collection admin` to `OD4B Sites`

1) Get the account names of the users in a tenant using People Search. Bear in mind that search has a limitation of returning a maximum of 500 rows on SharePoint Online. That will be 500 users in our case. So if your tenant as more than 500 users, you will need to call search in `batches` of 500 to get the account names of all the users.

2) Once we have the account names of the users, we need to get the url of their OneDrive for Business sites. We can do this by querying the CSOM UserProfile API

3) After getting the OneDrive for Business site urls, all we need to do is use the `SetSiteAdmin` function.

```
using Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security;

namespace CSOM.Console.Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Tenant Details
            string tenantAdminUrl = "https://tenantName-admin.sharepoint.com/";
            string tenantAdminLoginName = "admin@tenantName.onmicrosoft.com";
            string tenantAdminPassword = "password";
            string mySiteHostUrl = "https://tenantName-my.sharepoint.com";

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(tenantAdminUrl))
            {
                //Credentials
                var passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in tenantAdminPassword.ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(tenantAdminLoginName, passWord);

                //Get accountnames of users in the tenant
                var accountNames = GetUserAccountNames(clientContext);

                //Get OD4B site urls
                var OD4BSites = GetUserOD4BSites(mySiteHostUrl, clientContext, accountNames);

                //Set User as Site collection admin on the OD4B sites.
                SetAdminOnOD4BSites(clientContext, OD4BSites);

                System.Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static List<string> GetUserAccountNames(ClientContext clientContext)
        {
            //Use search to get the AccountNames of users in a tenant. 
            var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
            keywordQuery.QueryText = "*";
            keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid("b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31");
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("AccountName");
            keywordQuery.BypassResultTypes = true;
            var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
            var searchResults = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            var accountNames = new List<string>();
            if (searchResults.Value.Count > 0 && searchResults.Value[0].RowCount > 0)
            {
                foreach (var resultRow in searchResults.Value[0].ResultRows)
                {
                    accountNames.Add(resultRow["AccountName"].ToString());
                }

            }

            return accountNames;
        }

        private static List<string> GetUserOD4BSites(string mySiteHostUrl, ClientContext clientContext, List<string> accountNames)
        {
            var OD4BSites = new List<string>();

            foreach (var accountName in accountNames)
            {
                // Get the people manager instance
                var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);

                // Get the OneDrive for Business Site Url
                var OD4BSite = peopleManager.GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName, "PersonalSpace");

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                OD4BSites.Add(mySiteHostUrl + OD4BSite.Value);
            }

            return OD4BSites;
        }

        private static void SetAdminOnOD4BSites(ClientContext clientContext, List<string> OD4BSites)
        {
            var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);

            //Get login name of the current user
            var currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
            clientContext.Load(currentUser, u => u.LoginName);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //Iterate the site collectio urls
            foreach (var OD4BSite in OD4BSites)
            {
                try
                {
                    //assign the specified user (current user in this case) as the tenant admin. 
                    tenant.SetSiteAdmin(OD4BSite, currentUser.LoginName, true);
                    //Set the last parameter to false if you want to remove the user from the site collection admins

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    System.Console.WriteLine(OD4BSite);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    System.Console.WriteLine("Error on: " + OD4BSite + " " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are inclined to use `Rest`, then refer [Frank Marasco's: So you want to programmatically provision Personal Sites (One Drive for Business) in Office 365?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frank_marasco/archive/2014/03/25/so-you-want-to-programmatically-provision-personal-sites-one-drive-for-business-in-office-365.aspx) on msdn.