# Add personal site collection administrator programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile

I am looking for a way to add a site collection owner to personal site of a user.
 I can set the `ctx.Site.Owner` for other site collections, but for personal sites I am receiving Unauthorized exception at `ctx.ExecuteQuery()`. I am a global administrator for the tenant.

The same functionality is possible via GUI:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a Powershell function in my profile (it also handles loading all the CSOM modules too) that looks like this:

```
#This will handle iterating through all the OD4B sites that have been provisioned
    #and setting an eDiscovery SCA and any other SCAs as necessary
    $sca = "user@domain.com"

    $Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter your password" -AsSecureString
    $Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($me, $Password)
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($MysiteHost)
    $Context.Credentials = $Creds

    #Identify users in the Site Collection
    $Users = $Context.Web.SiteUsers
    $Context.Load($Users)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Create People Manager object to retrieve profile data
    $PeopleManager = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager($Context)

    Foreach ($User in $Users)
        {
        $UserProfile = $PeopleManager.GetPropertiesFor($User.LoginName)
        $Context.Load($UserProfile)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        If ($UserProfile.Email -ne $null){
            $UPP = $UserProfile.UserProfileProperties

            if($UserProfile.PersonalUrl.Contains("PersonImmersive")){
                continue
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "Setting SCAs for " $UserProfile.DisplayName -ForegroundColor Green
                Set-SPOUser -Site $UserProfile.PersonalUrl -LoginName $sca -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true
            }
        }  
    }
```

This iterates over all the OD4B sites and sets the owner, it could be adapted easily enough to supply a user or a URL.